# In a terminal with set editing-mode vi, why does Shift-F6 flip the case of all letters from cursor to second to last character?

Tags: terminal, bash

**This is in bash, with `set editing-mode vi` in my `~/.inputrc`.**

Say my command line looks like this

```bash
$ echo I am Enrico
```

and that my cursor is on the `m`.

If I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, the command line becomes

```bash
$ echo I aM eNRICo
```

Why is this the case?

---

Inside Vim, if I enter insert mode and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, I get `^[[29~` where the first character is represented as `^[`, and it's the escape character I can get by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

Now, I know `~` is for switching a case of a letter, but in `^[[29~` the `~` comes last, so any movement preceding it would be done before `~` can do anything, right?

Furthermore, in `:h ~`, I see that `~` doesn't take motion unless `'tildeop'` is set, which I don't know what it means for bash command line vi editing mode... But anyway, even if for some reason I was setting that option, `~` would take the `{motion}` after it, not before, so I would still not understand how `^[[29~` could be a `~{motion}`.

Comment: `~` doesn't take a motion, but it does take a `count`! Not sure why it's stopping before the `o`, though. Inside Vim, that sequence of keystrokes would exit insert mode, fail on `[2` because that's not a valid command, and then swap case of 9 characters with `9~`.

Comment: Aside: you should be able to use `<C-v><Shift-F6>` in bash too. Vim and bash's "vi mode" may not behave 100% identical, so you need to be careful referencing the Vim help for bash behaviour.